# Connect virtual machine(vulnhub machine/any machine) to host machine(parrot os)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

*Main machine*(Parrot OS)---->*Virtual Machine*(Vulnhub box/other virtual machines)

---

I want to connect my Host Machine (parrot os ) to my vulnhub machine So I can practice my pentesting skills. I cant connect my virtual machine that I have downloaded from vulnhub.com. I tried to connect by selecting Bridge network set to wlan0(I am using WiFi on my host machine ). It works on my VirtualBox(set to Bridge Network) but When I set BN to VMware... It doesn't work ! Any help will be appreciated !

---

---

Versions:

---

1. **VirtualBox** Graphical User Interface Version 6.1.4_Debian r136177
2. **VMware Workstation 15 Pro** 15.5.2 build-15785246
3. **Parrot Version** 5.4.0-4parrot1-amd64

Comment: Please indicate which software and version you are trying to run it from, Windows, Linux, macOS, other. So people at Super User can helping you better.

Comment: Hey ! Actually thing is my main machine which is parrot os and i want to connect it to vulnhub boxes or virtual machines running on VMware or VirtualBox... I dont want to make separate virtual machine of parrot os(My lappy cant handle running 2 virtual machines... It becomes too laggy !) so I can connect them using NAT... That's why I want to run 1 virtual machine(which will be vulnhub box) and I can connect it from my main os... I hope this helped !